# Vagrant + Virtualbox CPU utilization very low in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, virtualbox, cpu, vagrant

I am running a Virtualbox VM that runs Ubuntu 14.04 LTS provisioned by Vagrant. There are 2 physical cores in my computer (Dell Inspiron Laptop), which I assigned both of them to the VM (this I checked from VirtualBox GUI also).

I am running a cpu intensive Postgresql query on the VM, which utilizes 99-100% of the processing power (as shown by 'top' command in linux), but the CPU allocated to VirtualBox (VBoxHeadless.exe) in Windows is around 8-9%. Thus, the overall performance of the VM suffers. How can I improve the performance?

Comment: Interesting question. Could you add a tag to specify the host OS?

Comment: It is Windows 8.1 (was in the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Researching more on this, I came to realize Windows was on a less aggressive power schedule. I switched it to 'High Performance' and it did help (daaa!). Now, VBoxHeadless.exe goes up to 35%, which is more reasonable since I know that postgresql cannot utilize multiple cores for one task (so 50% would be the limit for it); whenever I send two of such queries simultaneously, it goes up to around 70%, and the cpu fan starts to roar!.